# Characteristic function of complex valued random variable

Tags: probability, characteristic-functions

1) How is Characteristic function of a complex valued random variable defined? Should it be considered as vector of real random variables or the [definition in wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_%28probability_theory%29) be used?

2) Also how is the characteristic function defined for vector of complex random variables?

3) If $Z=\begin{bmatrix}
        X \\
        Y \\
        \end{bmatrix}$ with $X$ and $Y$ independent real random variables,is the characteristic function of $Z$ equals convolution of C.F of $X$ and C.F of $Y$? (Since $f_Z(z)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$) and will that be the same as the definition of C.F for vector of random variables?

Comment: What is $[X;Y]^T$?